# Disable click Youtube iframe in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I need to disable click of the Youtube `iframe` or set difference click,.
I tried to put a `div` in front the `iframe` but it doesn't work.

Here is my code, works in Chrome but not in Mozilla:

```
$(".youtube").each(function () {
    var div = this;
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var x = offset.left;
    var y = offset.top;
    var height = $(this).height();
    var width = $(this).width();
    var divInFront = '<div  style="position:absolute; height:' + height + '; width:' + width + '; top:' + y + '; left:' + x + ';"  ></div>';
    $("body").append(divInFront);
});
```

Comment: Add `z-index` to your `div`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking

Comment: I've tried z-index and still not working

Comment: Add a wrapper `div` (`position: relative;display: inline-block`) for the `iframe` and append the cover to that wrapper. Then set also `background: #fff; opacity: 0;` for the cover. In modern browsers you can also try `pointer-events: none;` for the cover. Something like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NBKc/).

Comment: If is a Youtube video doesn't work